# Problema de armazenamento de valor de uma variável em Arduino: ele lê um valor e guarda por dois ciclos, há como resolver isso?

Tags: python, arduino, serial

Meu projeto consiste em um programa Arduino usando o módulo RFID, para ler frequências de cartão, para liberar uma catraca (de modo similar aos ônibus). Um programa em Python vai ler essa frequência printada na serial do Arduino e vai em um banco de dados validar: caso a frequência existe, ele retorna '1' pro Arduino; caso não exista, ele retorna 0.

No Arduino, tenho uma variável que recebendo 1 libera a catraca, e recebendo 0 bloqueia:

```
if (Serial.available())
  {
  validacao = Serial.read();
  Serial.parseInt();
  }

if (validacao == '1')
  {
    ...Liberado...
  }

else if (validacao == '0')
  {
    ...Bloqueado...
  }
```

E o programa de validação em Python:

```
import mysql.connector 
import serial 
import time 

#-------------------CONEXAO COM BANCO-------------------#
conexao_banco_de_dados = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="1202", db="Arduino") 

validar = conexao_banco_de_dados.cursor()

validar.execute("SELECT frequencia FROM usuarios") 

dados_frequencia = [i[0] for i in list(validar)]
#-------------------------------------------------------#

#-------------------CONEXAO SERIAL----------------------#
conexao_monitor_serial_arduino = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 9600, timeout=1.7)
#-------------------------------------------------------#

#---------------------MAIN------------------------------#

print('\n{}Programa em andamento!{} \nPrecione {}Ctlr + Alt - C{} para interromper.\n'.format('\033[1m', '\033[0m', '\033[3m', '\033[0m'))

while 1:
    uid = conexao_monitor_serial_arduino.readline()

    if (uid in dados_frequencia):
        conexao_monitor_serial_arduino.write('1')  
        print ("1")

    if (uid not in dados_frequencia):       
        conexao_monitor_serial_arduino.write('0')  
        print ("0")
```

O problema é que quando eu passo um cartão, o Arduino armazena a variável dele por dois ciclos, quando era pra ser só em um ciclo. Exemplo: cartão X passa e cartão Y não passa. Se eu passar o cartão X primeiro, o Python manda 1 pro Arduino e armazena. A partir de aqui,todo o cartão que está cadastrado passa normalmente. Mas se eu resolva passar o cartão Y, que não está cadastrado,o Python envia normalmente o 0, mas o Arduino primeiro libera, e na segunda vez que eu passo já bloqueia normal todos; e assim sucessivamente. Tem como corrigir esse método de armazenamento do Arduino para não precisar passar o cartão duas vezes pra ser o procedimento certo?

Answer (score 0):

Opa, que bom ver que você seguiu a dica que te dei de enviar somente a UID pelo serial e esperar a resposta se existe ou não, e não esta mais gravando as UIDs do banco na memória do arduino.
Sobre o seu problema atual você poderia limpar a variável logo depois de liberar no arduino, assim:

```
if (validacao == '1')
{
  ...Liberado...
  //Depois que fez a liberacao na catraca seta validacao pra 0.
  validacao = 0;
}

else if (validacao == '0')
{
  ...Bloqueado...
}
```

Comment: Opa, obrigado por antes! Sobre essa solução, já tentei. Não dá certo.

Comment: https://github.com/Neoiluminista/catraca/blob/Integra%C3%A7%C3%A3o-Incompleta/integracao_enxuta_buggada.ino

Comment: Dá certo com um fixo. Eu fiz tanto com cartão sem banco de dados, quanto usando o programa em Python sem cartão. Quando é fixo, não tem problema de armazenamento, já que não vai mudar constantemente.

Comment: Deu certo, substitui o _if availible_ por um _while_ e aumentei o alcance das chaves. Só entrar no link se quiser ver as diferenças. Agora o projeto tá aceitável, mas ainda buggado. Ele primeiro tem que receber uma frequência, então o LED interno RX fica piscando muito rápido. Tira o cartão, e 2s depois o LED interno X1 pisca; aí sim você pode aproximar o cartão e ele bloqueia ou libera de forma certa. O bug é que ele sempre bloqueia primeiro, depois ele roda o certo automaticamente. Então, se for um cartão que libere, ele bloqueia -> libera; se for um que bloqueia, ele bloqueia -> bloqueia.

Comment: Estarei trabalhando agora para resolver isso, para que não cancele sempre antes e que não precise botar 2 vezes o cartão.

Comment: Resolvi o problema de ter que botar o cartão dos vezes. Só dar print de uma string na serial. Mas o bloqueio sempre de primeira permanece.

Comment: @NoahSaulz que bom que conseguiu resolver o problema anterior. Para evitar uma criar um texto só de comentários vamos apagar os comentários antigos e se possível poste a solução para sua própria pergunta, ou caso preferir, pode apagar a mesma, pois deixar ela sem reposta não tem sentido.

Comment: Certo, assim que eu conseguir debbugar a última coisa (sempre bloqueia antes), eu posto a solução.